# multidimensional discrete wavelet transform

Tags: c++, dwt

can anyone tell me the correct method to use the getOutputValue function in the following link? Also, how does the author get the 2nd and 3rd image from the code.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/385658/Multidimensional-Discrete-Wavelet-Transform

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, usage:

I haven't tried it yet, but from what I get you simply call `getOutputValue()` to get one result. The parameter is a vector containing the "coordinates" (based on the number of dimensions in your input).

Images:

In this example, the author obviously used the image data as the discrete values, e.g. a black pixel would be `0` and a white pixel would be `255` with all other shades of grey being inbetween (default 8 bit grayscale image).

He then used the output signal/result to recreate a image (i.e. interpret the values as pixels once again).

Comment: discrete values of the original image in getOutputValue()?